# Exclude current post from loop

Tags: php, wordpress, while-loop, categories

I want to add a Wordpress loop for a specific category in a post template that exculdes the current post.

I was suggested to use:

```
<?php
global $wp_query;
$cat_ID = get_the_category($post->ID);
$cat_ID = $cat_ID[0]->cat_ID;
$this_post = $post->ID;
query_posts(array('cat' => $cat_ID, 'post__not_in' => array($this_post), 'posts_per_page' => 14, 'orderby' => 'rand'));
?>
```

But I'm having trouble getting it to work.

My loops currently looks like this.

```
<div class="video">
    <?php
        $catquery = new WP_Query( 'category_name=video&posts_per_page=4' );
        while($catquery->have_posts()) : $catquery->the_post();
    ?>

    <div>
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
            <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
            <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
        </a>
    </div>

    <?php endwhile; ?>

    <p class="more">M<br>O<br>R<br>E</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code.

```
$postid = get_the_ID();
    $args=array(
      'post__not_in'=> array($postid),
      'post_type' => 'post',
       'category_name'=>'video',
      'post_status' => 'publish',
      'posts_per_page' => 4

    );


    <div class="video">
        <?php
            $catquery = new WP_Query( $args );
            while($catquery->have_posts()) : $catquery->the_post();
        ?>

        <div>
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
                <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
            </a>
        </div>

        <?php endwhile; ?>

        <p class="more">M<br>O<br>R<br>E</p>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
'post__not_in' => array($post->ID)
```

Comment: How would I add this to the loop I have above?

Answer (score -1):

The two code blocks are using two different techniques for a Wordpress custom loop... the first modifies the global query, and the second creates a new custom query. I've outlined both below with your loop template.

**Example with suggested code, global query:**

Loop through the global $wp_query object in the loop code:

```
<div class="video">
<?php
    global $wp_query;
    $cat_ID = get_the_category($post->ID);
    $cat_ID = $cat_ID[0]->cat_ID;
    $this_post = $post->ID;
    query_posts(array('cat' => $cat_ID, 'post__not_in' => array($this_post), 'posts_per_page' => 14, 'orderby' => 'rand'));
?>

<!-- use the global loop here -->

<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>


    <div>
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
            <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
            <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
        </a>
    </div>

<?php endwhile; ?>

<p class="more">M<br>O<br>R<br>E</p
</div>
```

**Example with original code, custom query**:

Loop through the custom query, adding 'post__not_in':

```
<div class="video">
<?php
    $catquery = new WP_Query(     'category_name=video&posts_per_page=4&post__not_in=' . $post->ID );
    while($catquery->have_posts()) : $catquery->the_post();
?>

    <div>
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
            <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
            <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
        </a>
    </div>

    <?php endwhile; ?>

    <p class="more">M<br>O<br>R<br>E</p>
</div>
```

Sorry if my original answer was unclear, I initially thought you were combining the two code blocks.